# How to install pony-mode for Django in emacs

Tags: django, emacs

I'm new to emacs and i would like to install [pony-mode](https://github.com/davidmiller/pony-mode) for django. I've been struggling with the installation instructions but I have not found a way to make it work. Do i need to byte-compile all the .el files? How do I do that? Are there any dependencies that need to be installed? I've managed to get the following error: `pony-mode.el:83:1:Error: Cannot open load file: files-x`. Can someone provide a full set of instructions?

I'm using emacs GNU Emacs 23.1.1 on ubuntu 10.04

Answer (score 4):

I noticed that pony-mode is also available via package.el

I have package manager configured like so:

```
(require 'package)
(dolist (source '(("marmalade" . "http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/")
                  ("elpa" . "http://tromey.com/elpa/")))
  (add-to-list 'package-archives source t))
(package-initialize)
```

And then you should be able to run the `package-install` command and type `pony-mode` when prompted in the minibuffer.

Answer (score 2):

It works just fine for me

```
git clone http://github.com/davidmiller/pony-mode ~/Development/pony-mode

M-x byte-compile-file (compile only pony-mode.el)
```

And then add to .emacs:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/Development/pony-mode")
(require 'pony-mode)
```

Of course you would have to change the paths for yours... Be careful with the path in the load path function, no final / and no spaces

Comment: can you please show your .emacs file please? did you make the git clone?

Comment: from what I see files-x are part of the standard GNU Emacs http://repo.or.cz/w/emacs.git/blob/HEAD:/lisp/files-x.el so it looks like there is a problem with your installation, try to reinstall it or maybe upgrade to a newer version

Comment: After a lot of tests i found out that you first need to add the above lines to the .emacs file and then try to compile pony-mode.el. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @fusion I would be surprised if the order of those two made a difference. I suspect that you most likely fixed a load-path issue during your many tests :)

Comment: @david yeahh It hink so too... it's a classic mistake

Comment: @fernando-diaz-garrido Well you were right, the order does not make a difference. Mostly out of curiosity I tried to track the problem on another computer with the same version of ubuntu. It seems that the files-x.el is missing from the default installation of emacs.  Downloading it from the url above and byte-compiling it solves the problem. In my previous case i had already done that by I was confused and could't see that it was the real solution! Add this to your answer and i will accept it so any other users of ubuntu lucid don't get confused.

Answer (score 0):

The error "Cannot open load file: files-x" is unrelated to byte-compilation.

There is a file included in GNU Emacs 'files-x.el' which is required by pony-mode in order to set dir-local variables for per-project settings.

This error most likely means that the variable `load-path' is set such that it cannot find files-x.el.

(/usr/local/share/emacs/23.1/lisp/files-x.el would be a good first place to look in your case. 
C-h v load-path will allow you to inspect this variable.)

The installation instructions provided by @Fernando should work if your installation is standard

Comment: Finally I figured out that it was a problem with the default installation of emacs on ubuntu 10.04. See my last comment in Fernando Diaz Garrido's answer.